# Why does TCP Reno cut the congestion window in half when I get duplicate ACKs?

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm having a hard time understanding this conceptually.

Why does TCP Reno cut its congestion window in half when it detects triple duplicate ACKs and cuts its window to 1 segment when it times out?

I understand that Reno does this, but I'm not understanding exactly *why*. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

**The short answer**

- It makes your pipe full and improve your throughput.

**The long answer**

- Compare to `TCP Tahoe`, which has only two state `Slow Start` and 
  `Congestion Avoidance`, `TCP Reno` has another state called `Fast Recovery`.
- On a triple duplicate `Ack`,`TCP Reno` transitions to `Fast Recovery`.
- In the `Fast Recovery` state, it transitions back to `Congestion
  Avoidance` when it receives a new `Ack`, resetting the congestion
  window to be half of the congestion window size when it transitioned
  to the `Fast Recovery` state.
- On a timeout, it returns to `Slow Start` just as in `Congestion
  Avoidance`.
- On receiving a duplicate `Ack`, it increments the
  congestion  window by 1. (**Congestion Window Inﬂation**)

The reason not entering `Slow Start` state (meaning reduce the congestion window to 1) because receiving duplicate `Ack` tells TCP more than just a packet has been lost. The receiver can only generate the duplicate `Ack` when another segment is received, that segment has left the network and is in the receiver's buffer.

So still having data flowing between the two ends, and `TCP Reno` doesn't want to reduce the flow suddenly.

By halving the congestion window, staying in the `Congestion Avoidance` state,
`TCP Reno` improves network performance.

You can see a simple test about perfomance of `TCP Reno` and `TCP Tahoe`
in this [link](http://www2.ensc.sfu.ca/~ljilja/cnl/presentations/laxmi_mohamadreza/opnetwork08/subedi_najiminaini_trajkovic_opnetwork2008_presentation_edited.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The arrival of duplicate ACKs indicate that something has left the pipe, and is an indication of "not so serious congestion" and there are packet buffered, and possibly in flight so we want to keep the flow going so to speak. Reducing the congestion window to half reduces the time the pipe is empty (and there are congestion control flavors that does not reduce by that much).

A timeout is a sign of something more serious, so a more appropriate response would be to reduce the window a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a justification for the multiplicative decrease factor of 0.5 (as opposed to, for example, an additive decrease, or a larger multiplicative constant like 0.9), there is one in appendix D of [this paper](http://ee.lbl.gov/papers/congavoid.pdf) by [Van Jacobson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Jacobson), one of the designers of the original TCP congestion control algorithms.

Comment: See Appendix D: Window adjustment policy